# Selenium: Getting error with webElement or Webdriver "Drive" Variable

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation, testng

**New to automation. Help is greatly needed.**

Why am I getting a `NullPointerException`?

```
Error: Null pointer access: The variable driver can only be null at this 
     location
```

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import common.controls.PageVerified;


public class Google extends PageVerified{
        PageVerified PgVerif = new PageVerified();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
        
        @Test
            public void Login() throws Exception{
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https:Google.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("Test");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.className("lsb")).click();
            PgVerif.Verify();
            String a = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println(a);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("Test");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.className("sbico-c")).click();
            String b = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println(b);
            
            driver.close();
        }
```

Following is another class that I am calling where I get the error
and it is in separate package than the above.

```
package common.controls;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class PageVerified 
{
    public String Verify()
        {
            WebDriver driver = null ;
            String pagetitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb_70']")).getText();
                if(pagetitle != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(pagetitle + "Verified Successfully"  );
                    return pagetitle;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Error::Not Verified");
                }
                return null;
        }   
}
```

Comment: This post was asked and answered on StackOverflow.  In your Verify method, you define the driver as null, then you immediately try to use it on the next line as if it was initialized, and it's not, it's null.  This was explained in the other post, or is this some example from a web site somewhere that someone else is also using (not your own code?)

Comment: @BillHileman: Yes i understand that **you define the driver as null, then you immediately try to use it on the next line as if it was initialized, and it's not, it's null** but i am not able to resolve it, what would i do to resolve it?

Comment: @BillHileman - can you link to the answer, so we can close it here if in fact it is cross-posted?

Comment: @Kkat - If you did not understand SO answer, better is asking additional questions there. This looks like programming question. Seems that you just need to upgrade your coding skills - follow some tutorials, if you are not ready to debug your code. Bill explained it right.

Comment: @PeterMasiar I offered the same answer as the other post, but apparently the answer was not acceptable by the original poster since he/she wanted specific details on how to properly re-write the code, apparently, based upon the reply given.  There were way too many things wrong with the shown code, in my opinion.  Short answer, I haven't gone back to locate the other post, but we see this often when an "answer" is not sufficient for a poster, even when it's the correct answer.  Others have taken the time to answer in detail, so perhaps the question should stay.

Comment: @Kkat: `WebDriver driver = null ;` makes `driver` to be `null`. If you want `driver` to be something different, assign that thing (whatever is right for your code) and not the `null`. You cannot learn programming by just randomly copy-pasting code snippets and hoping that someone else makes them to work. That approach is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: @BillHileman - IMHO by providing code snippets which OP can copy-paste without understanding, poster provide OP dis-service: reinforce OP's cargo-cult approach without adding the understanding which OP lacks. Your answer is the only one trying to explain, not to provide a snippet to copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. From last  2 days i was not available to see the comments but after making the changes as suggested works for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You were getting null pointer exception because, though the `driver` is initialized in `Google` class.In this line `PgVerif.Verify();` Control shifts to `verify()` method and in that method you are declaring another variable for driver (like `WebDriver driver=null;`). 
So a new variable `driver` is created (and this variable is not the previously initialized one from `Google` class).

So there are two things that you can do.

1. While creating the `PageVerified` instance you can send the initialized driver instance into its constructor and use it in the `PageVerified` class.

   ```
   public class Google
   {
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     PageVerified PgVerif = new PageVerified(driver);
   ...
   }

   public class PageVerified 
   {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public PageVerified(WebDriver driver)
    {
            this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String verify()
    {
       String pagetitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("// [@id='gb_70']")).getText();
    ...
    }
   }
   ```
2. Send the initialized driver directly into the `verify()` method after initialization.

   ```
   public class Google
   {
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     PageVerified PgVerif = new PageVerified();
     ...
     PgVerif.verify(driver);
   }

   public class PageVerified 
   {
    public String verify(WebDriver driver)
    {
       String pagetitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("// [@id='gb_70']")).getText();
          ...
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as per below:
public WebDriver driver;

```
public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {

    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.driver = driver;

}

public void verifyTitle(String etitle) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(etitle));
        Reporter.log("Title is Matching: " + etitle, true);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Reporter.log("Title is not Matching: " + etitle, true);
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```